# DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm remaking a Discord music bot I made a while back in Discord.js `v12.5.3` and when I try and use any slash command except play it gives me this error:

---

> C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
> throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
> ^

> DiscordAPIError: 404: Not Found
> at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Programming\NodeJS\Discord bots\DJeff New\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14) {
> method: 'post',
> path: '/interactions/callback',
> code: 0,
> httpStatus: 404
> }

---

Here is how I pass the arguments and other stuff:

```
        interaction.reply = (client, response) => {
            client.api.interactions(this.id, this.token).callback.post({
                data: {
                    type: 4,
                    data: {
                        content: response,
                    },
                },
            });
        };
        command.execute(client, interaction, interaction.data.options || []);
```

And here's my skip.js file for reference:

```
module.exports = {
    name: "skip",
    usage: null,
    options: null,
    async execute(client, interaction, args) {
        var serverQueue = client.queue.get(interaction.guild_id);
        const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(interaction.guild_id);
        const userVoiceChannel = guild.members.cache.get(
            interaction.member.user.id
        ).voice.channel;
        if (!userVoiceChannel)
            return interaction.reply(
                client,
                "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command."
            );
        var clientVoiceChannel = client.voice.connections.get(
            interaction.guild_id
        );
        if (!clientVoiceChannel)
            return interaction.reply(
                client,
                "I need to be in a voice channel to execute this command."
            );
        if (
            clientVoiceChannel.channel.id !==
            guild.members.cache.get(interaction.member.user.id).voice.channel.id
        )
            return interaction.reply(
                client,
                "You need to be in the same voice channel as me to use this command."
            );

        if (!serverQueue)
            return interaction.reply(client, "Nothing is playing.");
        serverQueue.connection.dispatcher.end("Skipped the current video.");
        return interaction.reply(
            client,
            ":fast_forward: **|** Skipped the current video."
        );
    },
};
```